# how to apply word wrap in wideimage texts?

Tags: php, word-wrap

How can I write a long text to a small image using php wideimage?

Here is my php code i used,

```
$bg = WideImage::load("fbpostbg.png");
$final= $bg ->resize(400, 400);
$canvas = $final ->getCanvas();
$canvas->useFont('verdana.ttf', 14, $final->allocateColor(000, 000, 000));
$canvas->writeText('left +10', 'top +10', 'This is the text that I need to write to the above image, which is quite long...');

$final->output('jpg', 90);
```

This outputs with some text outside the image canvas and can not be seen...
I need to make word wrap in the text that we write to the image and need to get the image with full text in it.

I'm new to WideImage, help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php's wordwrap function see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

```
 $wrappedtext = wordwrap('This is the text that I need to write to the above image, which is quite long...', 60, "\n");
 $canvas->writeText('left +10', 'top +10',$wrappedtext);
```